# Linker is unable to find LLVM libraries on Windows using CLion and CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm, clion

I'm using latest version of CLion and MSYS Clang toolchain based on this [this tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/12/setting-up-clang-on-windows/).
I've built LLVM myself using [this](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html).

My CMakeList.txt:

```
project(SimpleProject)

set(LLVM_DIR D://LLVM/build/lib/cmake/llvm)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

# Set your project compile flags.
# E.g. if using the C++ header files
# you will need to enable C++11 support
# for your compiler.

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
separate_arguments(LLVM_DEFINITIONS_LIST NATIVE_COMMAND ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS_LIST})

# Now build our tools
add_executable(simple-tool main.cpp)

# Find the libraries that correspond to the LLVM components
# that we wish to use
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

# Link against LLVM libraries
target_link_libraries(simple-tool ${llvm_libs})
```

I'm trying to run LLVM Fibonacci example, but get errors as such:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: llvm::User::operator new(unsigned long long)
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/simple-tool.dir/main.cpp.obj:(main)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: llvm::Function::Function(llvm::FunctionType*, llvm::GlobalValue::LinkageTypes, unsigned int, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Module*)
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/simple-tool.dir/main.cpp.obj:(main)
```

[Full log](https://pastebin.com/JV1WPBaR)

Content of `${llvm_libs}`:

```
LLVMSupport;LLVMCore;LLVMIRReader
```

I can open this "symbols" through CLion, but for some reason linker is unable to find them.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `${llvm_libs}`

Comment: @AlanBirtles isn't it in the full log?
As far as I understand, line 5 of the log contains call to the linker

Comment: Your link points to a tutorial for Visual Studio, yet MSYS2 ships MinGW-flavored Clang. I don't think the libraries for the two are compatible.

Comment: MSYS2 ships prebuilt LLVM. Are you intentionally building it yourself?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm doing what I'm doing mostly because I'm lost to be honest
My goal at this point is to setup an LLVM project with CMake that is capable to compile Fibonacci at least.

Comment: Then install `mingw-w64-x86_64-llvm` from MSYS2. Remove `set(LLVM_DIR D://LLVM/build/lib/cmake/llvm)` and pray that `find_package` works.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat did that. Apparently find_package works.

Comment: But the problem is still there.

Comment: Thanks anyway, since that probably saved me from other kinds of errors.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I haven't change anything from original example
[Here it is](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/examples/Fibonacci/fibonacci.cpp)

Comment: @V.Govorov Sorry for the delay. I've managed to link this by specifying all the static libraries installed from the LLVM package (and then some winapi libraries), so you're probably just missing components in `llvm_map_components_to_libnames`. I'm not sure which ones you need though.